# Python Glade GTKBuilder Checkbutton

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade, gtkbuilder

How do I find if a GTKBuilder Checkbutton is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `checkbutton.get_active()`. What's this got to do with GtkBuilder?